# What is num_units argument in BahdanauAttention?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, sequence-to-sequence, nlp

I don't understand the argument `num_units` in TensorFlow's BahdanauAttention. It's defined as:

> num_units: The depth of the query mechanism.

which is unclear to me.

Comment: It would be kind of you to at least provide link to the implementation you're asking about.

Comment: @dedObed I am speaking about this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/BahdanauAttention
The question is what is `num_units` argument that it takes?